# How to update GUI without waiting ParallelFor threads to finish in C#?

Tags: .net, c#-4.0, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I have a GUI which I have to update. I want to use like Parallel.ForEach to Iterate certain code snippet and as soon as any thread completes , I have to inform GUI thread to update it self with the data processed by completed thread.

Parallel.For waits all threads to finish their execution where as in my case, I don't want to wait,  where as need to update GUI immediately.

What should I have to do? Is there any equivalent in TPL which allows to create multiple tasks equivalent to parallel.for and performs execution.

I would be much obliged to have nice answer.

Comment: Use the `await Task.WhenAny` pattern, as shown in the example under [Start Multiple Async Tasks and Process Them As They Complete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj155756.aspx#Anchor_2).

Comment: You can offload `ForEach` to a pool thread with `Task.Run`, or you can implement `ForEachAsync`: [Implementing a simple ForEachAsync](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2012/03/04/10277325.aspx).